# Splitting Nested List at every ['-1']

Tags: python, list

If I have a nested list like this:

```
[['01'], ['02'], ['-1'], ['03'], ['04']]
```

Is there a way I split this nested list at every `['-1']`?

So that it looks like this:

```
[[['01'], ['02']], [['03'], ['04']]]
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
lists = [['01'], ['02'], ['-1'], ['03'], ['04'], ['-1'], ['05'], ['-1']]

results = list()
prev_idx = 0
for idx, l in enumerate(lists):
    if l == ['-1']:
        results.append(lists[prev_idx:idx])
        prev_idx = idx+1

if prev_idx <= idx:     # the last group might be [] as shown in this case
    results.append(lists[prev_idx:])

print(results)
# Output
[[['01'], ['02']], [['03'], ['04']], [['05']]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group at every occurrence of your split value (here `['-1']`). `if not k` ensures that we leave out the split value itself.

```
orig = [['01'], ['02'], ['-1'], ['03'], ['04']]
from itertools import groupby
n = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(orig, lambda x: x == ['-1']) if not k]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a usecase for *groupby*

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = [['01'], ['02'], ['-1'], ['03'], ['04'], ['-1'], ['05'], ['06']]    
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(l, lambda x: x == ['-1']) if not k]
[[['01'], ['02']], [['03'], ['04']], [['05'], ['06']]]
```

[itertools.groupby docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Answer (score 0):

A good old fashioned loop should do it:

```
l = [['01'], ['02'], ['-1'], ['03'], ['04']]

new = []

current = []  # Build a new list here
for i, item in enumerate(l):
    if item != ['-1']:
        current.append(item)
        if i == len(l) - 1:  # If the item is the last in the list
            new.append(current)
    else:
        new.append(current)
        current = []

>>>  [[['01'], ['02']], [['03'], ['04']]]
```